# Get responseStream after writing a stream

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am a little confused about streaming with `WebClient` (WC)

> 1. Data is available and I start `WC.OpenWriteAsync(Uri)` on Silverlight side. WORKS
> 2. Data comes to my server and I can read data to my harddisc by reading the stream using `context.Request.InputStream`. WORKS
> 3. Modified Data is uploading from Server by using `Context.Response.OutputStream` WORKS
> 4. How to get this stream now in my Silverlight App?

WC in Silverlight side does not server any stream information of new data. I cannot download data from sever. If I start again with `WC.OpenReadAsync(Uri)` the WC does start a new request but does not download the data from server.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather bizare design choice to that `WebClient`. Its bizare because, in my experience, its a rare "POST" that only accepts content and doesn't send anything in return.

You will need to use `WebRequest` directly to handle both post and response.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Youre right like it seems. But I am working now since hours to get this stream to write and read content. I've found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx which does not work with silverlight. In Silverlight all calls are only async available. While watching over the `ManualResetEvent` and `BeginGetResponse` and `BeginGetRequestStream` which does not match with the samples, I gave up to do that. If anyone can recommend a working class where I can write binary and read binary, I would be pleased to get it.